# How to prove that the Galois group of a normal extension transitively permutes the factors of an irreducible polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

How to do the following problem?

> Let $K$ be a normal extension of $F$, and let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial over $F$. Let $g(x)$
>   and $p(x)$ be monic irreducible factors of $f(x)$ in $K[x]$. Prove that there is a $z\in\operatorname{Gal}(K/ F)$,
>   with $z(g)=p$.

Comment: I think this is contained in the book: *Foundations Of Algebraic Geometry* by **A.Weil**.  If you are interested you can have a look into it. I will vouch for this after I have the access to that book again.

Answer (score 7):

Let $N/F$ be a normal extension, let $X$ be an indeterminate, let $f\in F[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial, and let $g_1,g_2\in N[X]$ be irreducible monic factors of $f$.

We want to find an $F$-automorphism of $N$ which maps $g_1$ to $g_2$.

Let $N^a$ be an algebraic closure of $N$, and $\alpha_i$ a root of $g_i$ in $N^a$.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $F$ being $f$, there is an $F$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $N^a$ mapping $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_2$.

As $N/F$ is normal, we have $\sigma N=N$.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha_i$ over $N$ being $g_i$, our automorphism $\sigma$ maps $g_1$ to $g_2$.

Comment: An optimally elegant proof !

Answer (score 0):

Under the hypotheses, $f$ splits completely over $\bf K$, so $g$ and $p$ are linear. Thus the problem reduces to showing that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $f$ in $\bf K$ then there's an element of the Galois group that takes $\alpha$ to $\beta$. The proof of that result is in every exposition of Galois Theory.

EDIT: as awllower indicates, I misread the problem, and thought it was assumed that $f$ has a root in $\bf K$.

Comment: Why does $f$ split completely over $K$? It is supposed to be irreducible only, is it not?

Comment: If $f$ has one root in $K$, then it splits of course, but I see no reason to assume so...

Comment: Just consider $KL$, where $L$ is the splitting field of $f$.